# How can I align the arrows?

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices, arrows

This is a picture of what I would like to get and what I actually get.

[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\title{graphique}\newcommand{\cellsize}{0.5}
\newcommand{\circlesize}{0.35}

\newcommand{\printwhitecell}[2][]{\node[draw=gray, semithick, fill=white, minimum width=\cellsize cm, minimum height=\cellsize cm] at #2 {#1};} 
\newcommand{\printblackcell}[1]{\node[draw=gray, semithick, fill=black, minimum width=\cellsize cm, minimum height=\cellsize cm] at #1 {};} 
\newcommand{\printcircle}[1]{\draw[gray, semithick, fill=gray] #1 circle (\circlesize cm/2);} 
\newcommand{\printcell}[2]{%
    \if#1w%
        \printwhitecell{#2}%
    \else%
        \if#1b%
            \printblackcell{#2}%
        \else%
            \if#1c%
                \printwhitecell{#2}%
                \printcircle{#2}%
            \else%
                \if#1C%
                    \printblackcell{#2}%
                    \printcircle{#2}%
                \else
                    \printwhitecell[#1]{#2}%
                \fi%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}


\newcommand{\printmatrix}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \line[count=\i] in #2 {
        \foreach \cell[count=\j] in \line {
            \printcell{\cell}{(\j*\cellsize,-\i*\cellsize)}
        }
        \xdef\width{\j}
    }
    \node at ({0.5*(\width+1)*\cellsize}, {(-\i -1)*\cellsize}) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

 \printmatrix{}{{
            {b,w,w,w},
            {w,b,w,w},
            {w,w,b,w},
            {w,w,w,b}%  % 
        }} {\LARGE$\xrightarrow{}$}%
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,b,w,w},
            {w,w,b,w},
            {w,w,w,b},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}{\LARGE$\xrightarrow{}$}%
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,w,b,w},
            {w,w,w,b},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}{\LARGE$\xrightarrow{}$}%
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,w,w,b},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}
        {\LARGE$\xrightarrow{}$}%
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}


\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can we replicate your current setup? It would be ideal to see how `\printmatrix` is constructed. So, the suggestion would be to provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: Thank you clemens. And I will add a setup, sorry Werner.

Comment: I cannot add it on my original post via the edit, it says something like you don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: Here is the image I cannot put them both on my post: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LqhJF.png

Comment: Thank you azetina, but can someone explain me why I had these problems?

Answer (score 2):

We can use the fact, that dimensions of cells are known. The arrows are a bit deeper than the central line, but they probably have `S_c`'s over the, hence the effect of neglecting vertical dimension of lines in matrix is compensated. The last matrix is in the new line, because `\textwidth` is too small.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\title{graphique}\newcommand{\cellsize}{0.5}
\newcommand{\circlesize}{0.35}

\newcommand{\printwhitecell}[2][]{\node[draw=gray, semithick, fill=white, minimum width=\cellsize cm, minimum height=\cellsize cm] at #2 {#1};} 
\newcommand{\printblackcell}[1]{\node[draw=gray, semithick, fill=black, minimum width=\cellsize cm, minimum height=\cellsize cm] at #1 {};} 
\newcommand{\printcircle}[1]{\draw[gray, semithick, fill=gray] #1 circle (\circlesize cm/2);} 
\newcommand{\printcell}[2]{%
    \if#1w%
        \printwhitecell{#2}%
    \else%
        \if#1b%
            \printblackcell{#2}%
        \else%
            \if#1c%
                \printwhitecell{#2}%
                \printcircle{#2}%
            \else%
                \if#1C%
                    \printblackcell{#2}%
                    \printcircle{#2}%
                \else
                    \printwhitecell[#1]{#2}%
                \fi%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}


\newcommand{\printmatrix}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-1.5cm] % here -PS
    \foreach \line[count=\i] in #2 {
        \foreach \cell[count=\j] in \line {
            \printcell{\cell}{(\j*\cellsize,-\i*\cellsize)}
        }
        \xdef\width{\j}
    }
    \node at ({0.5*(\width+1)*\cellsize}, {(-\i -1)*\cellsize}) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}


 \printmatrix{}{{
            {b,w,w,w},
            {w,b,w,w},
            {w,w,b,w},
            {w,w,w,b}%  % 
        }} {\LARGE$\xrightarrow{S_c}$}%
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,b,w,w},
            {w,w,b,w},
            {w,w,w,b},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}{\LARGE$\xrightarrow{}$}%
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,w,b,w},
            {w,w,w,b},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}{\LARGE$\xrightarrow{}$}%
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,w,w,b},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}
        {\LARGE$\xrightarrow{}$}%
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}


\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All I did was modify your `\printmatrix` macro to wrap the `tikzpicture` as follows:

```
\raisebox{-2.5\dimexpr\cellsize cm}{...}
```

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\title{graphique}\newcommand{\cellsize}{0.5}
\newcommand{\circlesize}{0.35}

\newcommand{\printwhitecell}[2][]{\node[draw=gray, semithick, fill=white, minimum width=\cellsize cm, minimum height=\cellsize cm] at #2 {#1};} 
\newcommand{\printblackcell}[1]{\node[draw=gray, semithick, fill=black, minimum width=\cellsize cm, minimum height=\cellsize cm] at #1 {};} 
\newcommand{\printcircle}[1]{\draw[gray, semithick, fill=gray] #1 circle (\circlesize cm/2);} 
\newcommand{\printcell}[2]{%
    \if#1w%
        \printwhitecell{#2}%
    \else%
        \if#1b%
            \printblackcell{#2}%
        \else%
            \if#1c%
                \printwhitecell{#2}%
                \printcircle{#2}%
            \else%
                \if#1C%
                    \printblackcell{#2}%
                    \printcircle{#2}%
                \else
                    \printwhitecell[#1]{#2}%
                \fi%
            \fi%
        \fi%
    \fi%
}


\newcommand{\printmatrix}[2]{
    \raisebox{-2.5\dimexpr\cellsize cm}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \line[count=\i] in #2 {
        \foreach \cell[count=\j] in \line {
            \printcell{\cell}{(\j*\cellsize,-\i*\cellsize)}
        }
        \xdef\width{\j}
    }
    \node at ({0.5*(\width+1)*\cellsize}, {(-\i -1)*\cellsize}) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}} 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

 \printmatrix{}{{
            {b,w,w,w},
            {w,b,w,w},
            {w,w,b,w},
            {w,w,w,b}%  % 
        }} {\LARGE$\xrightarrow{}$}%
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,b,w,w},
            {w,w,b,w},
            {w,w,w,b},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}{\LARGE$\xrightarrow{}$}%
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,w,b,w},
            {w,w,w,b},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}{\LARGE$\xrightarrow{}$}%
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,w,w,b},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}
        {\LARGE$\xrightarrow{}$}%
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}


\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get it all in a single line, one can change `\cellsize` to `0.4`.

[image]

If labels are needed on the right arrows, one may use the currently blank argument to `xrightarrow{}`.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an easier way to create your matrix, here's a possible solution. You could even make it further automatic, by setting a counter, but I thought you might want to change the command.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\title{graphique}

\tikzset{
  pics/square/.default={1},
  pics/square/.style={%
    code={%
    \draw[pic actions] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#1);%
}}}    

\newcommand\printmatrix[1]{%
\tikz[x=.4cm, y=.4cm, baseline=(a)]{%
\coordinate (a) at (3,3);
\clip (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\foreach \x [count=\xx starting from #1, evaluate=\xx as \yy using int((4+#1)-\xx)] in {1,...,4}{%
    \foreach \y in {1,...,4}{%
        \pic at (\x,\y) {square};%
    }%
    \pic[fill] at (\xx,\yy) {square};%
    }%
}%
}%

\newcommand\myrightarrow[1][]{\ensuremath{\raisebox{-2pt}{$\xrightarrow{#1}$}}}%

\begin{document}
\printmatrix{1} \myrightarrow \printmatrix{2} \myrightarrow \printmatrix{3} \myrightarrow \printmatrix{4} \myrightarrow \printmatrix{5}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The construction of the squares might be simplified, but that's another matter. You can use `baseline` for setting the placement with respect to the baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% the following two are just for the example
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%

\newcommand{\cellsize}{0.5}
\newcommand{\circlesize}{0.35}

\newcommand{\largeto}{\mbox{\LARGE${}\to{}$}}

\newcommand{\printwhitecell}[2][]{%
  \node[draw=gray, semithick, fill=white, minimum width=\cellsize cm, 
        minimum height=\cellsize cm] at #2 {#1};%
} 
\newcommand{\printblackcell}[1]{%
  \node[draw=gray, semithick, fill=black, minimum width=\cellsize cm,
         minimum height=\cellsize cm] at #1 {};%
} 
\newcommand{\printcircle}[1]{%
  \draw[gray, semithick, fill=gray] #1 circle (\circlesize cm/2);%
} 
\newcommand{\printcell}[2]{%
    \if#1w%
        \printwhitecell{#2}%
    \else
        \if#1b%
            \printblackcell{#2}%
        \else
            \if#1c%
                \printwhitecell{#2}%
                \printcircle{#2}%
            \else
                \if#1C%
                    \printblackcell{#2}%
                    \printcircle{#2}%
                \else
                    \printwhitecell[#1]{#2}%
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
}


\newcommand{\printmatrix}[2]{%
    \sbox0{$ $}% ensure the math font has been defined
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-3\dimexpr\cellsize cm\relax]
    \foreach \line[count=\i] in #2 {
        \foreach \cell[count=\j] in \line {
            \printcell{\cell}{(\j*\cellsize,-\i*\cellsize)}
        }
        \xdef\width{\j}
    }
    \node at ({0.5*(\width+1)*\cellsize}, {(-\i -1)*\cellsize}) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{center}

 \printmatrix{}{{
            {b,w,w,w},
            {w,b,w,w},
            {w,w,b,w},
            {w,w,w,b}%  % 
        }}\largeto
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,b,w,w},
            {w,w,b,w},
            {w,w,w,b},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}\largeto
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,w,b,w},
            {w,w,w,b},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}\largeto
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,w,w,b},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}\largeto
         \printmatrix{}{{
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w},
            {w,w,w,w}%  % 
        }}
\end{center}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]